# Are there still working photo widgets?

Tags: macos, photos, dashboard-widget, widgets

Under previous Mac OS's there were widgets like "Modern Moments" and "Desk Photo" to display photos on the Dashboard. I tried them under Mac OS 10.10(.1) and they do not seem to be working. I'd like to see photos of my family/partner occasionally, e.g., when I use the Dashboard. Are there widgets that still work?

(Hope this question isn't too specific.)